# how can we overide an approve button in approval related list

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I want to override the approve button in approval related list. Is there a way we can do it?
The idea is the delete a few records with certain criteria when an approve button is clicked. i want to run a apex code when an approve button is clicked and then submit the record for approval.

Any pointers to achieve it would be helpful.

Thanks

Pradip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally did a workaround to get this done. Instead of overriding the approve button i used the approval process and trigger to get this done

Here is what i did.

1. Added a new field called SentForApproval (checkbox) in the object, make sure this is not in any page layout so no one accidently checks or unchecks this field.
2. In the approval process made field update to the above field changing it to true.
3. This field update would fire an update trigger.
4. In your trigger check for if this field is updated, do what ever you want to do in the trigger.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately to do this you have to completely override the approval process by forcing users through a custom button flow, and you can't place that custom button on the approval history list or override the approve/reject link. Salesforce hasn't significantly enhanced the customizability of approval processes since its original implementation years ago.